# Getting text from h1 className

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

im trying to get the following text 'getthis' by using the agility pack.

```
<h1 class="point">getthis< span class="level">Niveau 0</span> </h1>
```

I've tried:

```
var links = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("point");
foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
{
    Console.WriteLine("AAAAA");
}

var varit = doc.DocumentNode
               .SelectSingleNode("//h1[@class='point']")
               .InnerText;

Console.WriteLine("WB2 TRUE ", varit.ToString());*

var varit = doc.DocumentNode
               .SelectSingleNode("//h1[@class='point']")
               .InnerHtml;

Console.WriteLine("WB2 TRUE ", varit.ToString());*
```

Why isn't my code working?

Comment: Make sure that doc has valid HTML DOM structure

Comment: Yes,             doc.Load(webBrowser1.DocumentStream); , within the same method

Comment: Just see what doc.DocumentNode
               .SelectSingleNode("//h1[@class='point']") is returning

Comment: Hi Malkam, ive tried that already, it doesnt return null or anything. So i want to get the inner text/html of that. BUt it doesnt work :S

Comment: Is  doc.DocumentNode .SelectSingleNode("//h1[@class='point']") returning valid HTMLNode?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```js
htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("h1")
    .Where(d => d.Attributes.Contains("class") && d.Attributes["class"].Value.Contains("point"))
    .First().InnerHtml;
```

this code:

```js
string html = "<h1 class=\"point\">getthis< span class=\"level\">Niveau 0</span> </h1>";
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);
            var str = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("h1").Where(d => d.Attributes.Contains("class") && d.Attributes["class"].Value.Contains("point")).First().ChildNodes[0].InnerText;
```

returns: "getthis"

Comment: Hi Tomer, thanks for ur answer. But its not working, do you have any other code you think would fit?

Comment: Try using InnerText Instead of InnerHtml

Comment: I keep getting an; InvalidOperationException

Comment: Checking it up For you

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this question after finding this out:

var a = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h1").Skip(0).Take(1).Single();